# Upper Function is not working in out cursor

Tags: oracle, function, select, cursor

I tried to execute the select query with UPPER function that's working fine, while trying to execute through out cursor in oracle, it's not working. kindly tell what i am did wrong here?

**QUERY**:

```
SELECT ISSUEID,CATEGORY_1,CATEGORY_2,CATEGORY_3 FROM ISSUES 
WHERE  UPPER(CATEGORY_2)=UPPER('ORDERNAME');
```

**OUT CURSOR:**

```
OPEN OUT_CURSOR FOR SELECT ISSUEID,CATEGORY_1,CATEGORY_2,CATEGORY_3 FROM ISSUES 
WHERE  UPPER(CATEGORY_2)=UPPER('ORDERNAME');
```

**Complete Procedure:**

```
PROCEDURE ISSUE_SEARCH(
IN_ISSUEID IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
IN_ORDERJOURNEY IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
OUT_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSIDE IF..');
  OPEN OUT_CURSOR FOR SELECT ISSUEID,CATEGORY_1,CATEGORY_2,CATEGORY_3, FROM ISSUES 
WHERE  UPPER(CATEGORY_2)=UPPER('IN_ORDERJOURNEY');
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
OUT_CURSOR :=null;
END ISSUE_SEARCH;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: While execute query alone output values are coming, but while tried same thing in stored procedure through out cursor, output is not coming

Comment: Show your code that you say is "not working" and what output you expect to see.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Updated question with the complete procedure

Comment: @BobC More than one row for the select query output

Comment: IN your SQL, you are comparing to ORDERNAME; in your PL/SQL, you are comparing to IN_ORDERJOURNEY.

Comment: @BobC Both are same only, input naming i did like this

Comment: @BobC Kindly check the Procedure

Comment: In addition, if no rows are found, you are silently hiding the fact

Comment: may i know why output is not populating in out cursor?

Comment: Two Questions: 1. Does this predicate return data (because it's different to your plain SQL statement): WHERE  UPPER(CATEGORY_2)=UPPER('IN_ORDERJOURNEY') 2. Can you share the code that calls ISSUE_SEARCH

Comment: 1. IN_OrderJourney is an input parameter in Stored Procedure. Value i need to pass in plain SQL Statement

Comment: 2. i shared already complete procedure

Comment: what details you expecting for this? can you ask clearly

Comment: `in stored procedure through out cursor, output is not coming` - well, you need read data from the cursor and print that data in calling code/application, please show how you call this procedure and how your code does read and print data from the cursor.

Comment: 1. You have quotes around IN_ORDERJOURNEY, so the predicate is a literal, not the value passed in. 2. You need to pass the results out to something via your sys_refcursor - presumable some calling procedure. Take a look at the example in this link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets

Comment: i am calling this procedure manually.

Comment: Your `OUT_CUR` is empty or null ? And how are you validating the output of it?

Comment: Again, please show the code used to call this procedure